# Just finished updating Centos and installing httpd on a vm, but can't get to the test page using the ssh ip

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, lamp

I just got a brand new vm to run Apache on, but unfortunately I can't access it from outside the server (which is accessing the server due to a curl test). I am using CentOs 7 and followed these instructions up to testing the server: https://www.godaddy.com/help/build-a-lamp-stack-linux-apache-mysql-php-centos-7-17344 When I do go to the ip, it says that the site can't be reached/timed out. I checked firewalld and iptables and both have not yet been enabled or started. What are some common fallacies that I should check for?

Edit: Also, I am getting a warning that says: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using x.x.x.x. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message. What do I do with this, as it is a remote vm? I have the ssh ip and this new ip, so I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-messge

Answer (score 0):

For all those wondering what was happening, ensure that the ports on the main server are being forwarded to the virtual machine. I followed this tutorial and it all worked: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-setup-endpoints/